# How to make DateTime look nice while using dm-timestamps

Tags: ruby, postgresql, datetime

I am making a Sinatra app and using PostgreSQL and datamapper. The objective was to make it so when a user makes a post it shows the timestamp. I read somewhere that you can use dm-timestamps so I put it in my gemfile and bundled, then required the gem in my model. The DateTime is appearing, however it looks ugly.

I have been trying for ages to make it look nice with the MM DD YYYY appearing before the time, but no matter what I do it doesn't work.

Right now I have `post.content.created_by` in my index.erb file which allows the message along with the timestamp to appear. In my model it says

```
require 'dm-timestamps'
class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :content, String
  property :created_at, DateTime
end
```

It seems that if I try to call `<%= "#{ post.created_at.strftime("%H:%M on %d/%m/%y") }" %>`

It doesn't like the method .strftime even though I've seen the same method work for other people if they didn't use "created_at" which is given to you by `dm-timestamps`.

Sorry if the answer seems obvious to anyone, I am very new to this.

Comment: what does `post.created_at.class` return?

Comment: @Anthony it returns DateTime

Comment: can you copy and paste the error in your question please